# Find the Unrestricted Grammar for the language: L = {(a^i b^i)^j (c^k d^k)^j | i, j, k ≥ 1}

Tags: context-free-grammar, finite-automata, turing-machines, formal-languages

I'm having trouble determining a grammar for the L language. I've developed something that came close, but it's still not quite enough:

S → XSY | Z

X → aXb | ab

Y → cYd | cd

cZd → cd

This grammar I made accepts words that shouldn't belong to the language, like: "aabbabcdcd"; I wanted a grammar that would only produce words like this: (a²b²)³(c¹d¹)³ = "aabbaabbaabbcdcdcd"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to find context-free grammar for the above language. I  doubt if it is possible.
I'm not sure, but I would like to share my thoughts

To prove it is not possible, I would use [pumping lemma for context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages)

For simplicity let pumping length, `p = i = j = k`

consider the string `s = (a^p b^p)^p (c^p d^p)^p` which is an element of language L. Clearly `|s| > p`

We split `s` as `s = uvxyz`. We nee to show that `u(v^i)x(y^i)z` is not an element of L for `i>=0`

Consider following cases

- `v` and `y` contain only a's: Clearly, we are not producing enough b's hence such strings cannot be elements of L. For the same reason, we can rule out the cases where `v` and `y` contain exactly 1 element.
- Since `|vxy|<=p`, we don't expect combination of (a,c), (a,d) and (b,d) in (v,y)
- `v` and `y` contain only a's and b's: In this case, we may be able to produce the same number of a's and b's, but the number of (a^i b^i) terms will increase (j+something). We are not producing enough (c^k d^k) terms. Hence such strings are not elements of L. Case is similar when `v` and `y` contain c's and d's
- `v` and `y` contain only c's and d's: Same as the first case.

Hence by contradiction, given language is not context-free.

I repeat I am not so sure about this. Thanks!